# npx expo run:android failed

Tags: react-native, expo

npx expo run:android
(node:15808) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :expo-application
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-constants
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-file-system
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-font
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-keep-awake
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-modules-core
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-splash-screen
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules

- expo-application (5.1.1)
- expo-constants (14.2.1)
- expo-file-system (15.2.2)
- expo-font (11.1.1)
- expo-keep-awake (12.0.1)
- expo-modules-core (1.2.7)
- expo-splash-screen (0.18.2)

WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :lottie-react-native
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> AAR for react-native-reanimated has been found
> D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-71-jsc.aar

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core'

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
> warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
> warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
> D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\android\app\src\main\java\host\exp\exponent\MainActivity.java:19: error: package R does not exist
> setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
> ^
> D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\android\app\src\main\java\host\exp\exponent\MainActivity.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
> return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED, new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
> ^
> symbol:   variable BuildConfig
> location: class MainActivity
> D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\android\app\src\main\java\host\exp\exponent\MainApplication.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
> return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
> ^
> symbol: variable BuildConfig
> D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\android\app\src\main\java\host\exp\exponent\MainApplication.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
> return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
> ^
> symbol: variable BuildConfig
> D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\android\app\src\main\java\host\exp\exponent\MainApplication.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
> return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
> ^
> symbol: variable BuildConfig
> D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\android\app\src\main\java\host\exp\exponent\MainApplication.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
> if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
> ^
> symbol:   variable BuildConfig
> location: class MainApplication
> 6 errors
> 3 warnings

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 20s
224 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 220 up-to-date
Error: D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
at cp.emit (D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
...
at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
at spawnGradleAsync (D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
at Object.assembleAsync (D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
at runAndroidAsync (D:\santhosh\ecommerce-app-main\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:31:24)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

i need to resolve this errors

Comment: Hi @Sandy. have you upgraded you Gradle version or your JDK version lately ?